# nsprogressindictor progress not getting fully completing after nsurldownload in cocoa webview

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsprogressindicator, nsurldownload

My progress indicator is not working in cocoa webview I used this code -

```
   -(void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response { 
                 NSLog(@"downl didreceiveresponse here"); 
                 NSLog(@"Recieved reponse with expected length: %lli", [response expectedContentLength]); 
                payload=0; 
                [payload setLength:0]; 
                [progrssbar setMaxValue:[response expectedContentLength]] ; 
                [self setProgrssbar:progrssbar]; 
        } 
            - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
        { 
              NSLog(@"Recieving data. Incoming Size: %li Total Size: %li", (unsigned long)[data length], (unsigned long)[payload length]); 
              [payload appendData:data]; 
              [progrssbar setDoubleValue:[payload length]]; 
         } 
  - (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didReceiveDataOfLength:(unsigned)length 
   { 
            NSLog(@"downl receivedata here%i",length); 
            [progrssbar setHidden:NO]; 
            [progrssbar setIndeterminate:NO]; 
            [progrssbar startAnimation:self]; 
            [progrssbar setDoubleValue:(double)length]; [progrssbar displayIfNeeded];
     }
```

Comment: Please use code formatting while adding code in your question, people will be able to help you only if they understand it clearly.

Comment: thanks a lot i will use code formatting

Comment: Could you give us some more detail please, than the vague "not working"

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is payload declared as? I used a similar code where I declared `NSMutableData *payload` and then in `-(void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` I used `payload=[NSMutableData data]` instead of your `payload=0`, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: from this your progress bar downloaded fully?

Comment: Actually I used the delegate methods `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`, `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`, `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` and `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`, I would try substituting these to the first and the third method you use.